# InvalidRegistration error while send push notifications to android with rails backend

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send push notifications to android device using rails backend. I'm using pushmeup gem to do this. But when send notifications to device i got InvalidRegistration error in response. is any one facing same problem. help......

Comment: Make sure you are using correct server registration key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved. I'm using invalid device token.